# unable to access hash of array element created using XML parser

Tags: perl

My XML Parser looks as below:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'Symmetrix' => {
        'Masking_View' => {
            'View_Info' => {
                'Initiators' => {
                    'user_node_name' => [
                        '5001438001725614',
                        '5001438001725714'
                    ],
                    'user_port_name' => [
                        '5001438001725614',
                        '5001438001725714'
                    ],
                    'wwn' => [
                        '5001438001725614',
                        '5001438001725714'
                    ]
                },
                'port_grpname' => 'PG_1E0_2E0'
            }
        },
        'Symm_Info' => {
            'symid' => '000295900074'
        }
    }
};
```

I am trying to pull element of `wwn`. But I'm not able to get through.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin

use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0];
my $detail_info = XMLin("$input_file");

# Loop through each view_info
$detail_info->{Symmetrix}{Masking_View}{View_Info} = [ $detail_info->{Symmetrix}       {Masking_View}{View_Info} ] if ref ($detail_info->{Symmetrix}{Masking_View}{View_Info})   ne 'ARRAY';
foreach my $view_info  (@{$detail_info-> {Symmetrix}{Masking_View}{View_Info}})
{
      $view_info->{Initiators} = [$view_info->{Initiators}] if ref ($view_info->    {Initiators}) ne 'ARRAY';
foreach my $wwn (keys %{$view_info->{Initiators}})
    {
     my @flags = ();
     push (@flags,"$wwn:$view_info->{Initiators}{$wwn}";
     print @flags;
     #"{$wwn->{wwn}}";
    }
}
```

I am getting output as below;

```
{ARRAY(0x20c8904)}
```

I am looking for `wwn` element in single line of different line.

Comment: Also provide the XML input file.

Comment: Its big file, how do i do that?, instead I pasted XML parsed o/p

Answer (score 1):

You're producing too much code to distinguish arrayref values from non-reference values. [Strict mode](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple#STRICT-MODE) requires you to set the `ForceArray` options, and thus you can be certain that every value is an arrayref, even if there's just one element in it.

```
use strictures;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
my $detail_info = XMLin($ARGV[0], ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => []);
# $detail_info is {
#     Symmetrix => [
#         {
#             name      => 'Masking_View',
#             View_Info => [
#                 {
#                     Initiators => [
#                         {
#                             user_node_name => [5001438001725614, 5001438001725714],
#                             user_port_name => [5001438001725614, 5001438001725714],
#                             wwn            => [5001438001725614, 5001438001725714]
#                         }
#                     ],
#                     port_grpname => 'PG_1E0_2E0'
#                 }
#             ]
#         },
#         {
#             name  => 'Symm_Info',
#             symid => '000295900074'
#         }
#     ]
# }
my @flags;
for my $view_info (@{ $detail_info->{Symmetrix}[0]{View_Info} }) {
    for my $initiator (@{ $view_info->{Initiators} }) {
        push @flags, $initiator->{wwn};
    }
}
# @flags is (
#     [
#         5001438001725614,
#         5001438001725714
#     ]
# )
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier as well and o/p is blank which is same when ran with your script.